# How to get the match ID in PSM (Propensity Score Method) in R

Tags: r

I am performing Propensity Score Matching by package 'MatchIt' in R.
Here is my code.

```
set.seed(9527)
m.out<-matchit(Severe ~ age+Sex,method = "nearest",ratio=4,data=data_m)
summary (m.out,standardize = T)
m.data <- match.data (m.out)
```

It works well and I am going to conduct conditional logistic regression using clogit in package 'survival' with the code

```
model<-clogit(Severe~.+strata(stratum),data=data)
```

However, my matched data didn't contain the match ID which may fill into 'strata()' above.

And I try

```
m.out[["match.matrix"]]
```

to get some information

```
     1      2      3      4     
4    "595"  "812"  "612"  "605" 
5    "640"  "814"  "471"  "842" 
7    "402"  "670"  "1057" "482" 
11   "553"  "888"  "460"  "1416"
15   "635"  "14"   "920"  "210" 
16   "1444" "99"   "857"  "485" 
17   "895"  "1353" "924"  "1268"
22   "73"   "600"  "1316" "414" 
25   "168"  "1262" "454"  "494" 
71   "1322" "318"  "1037" "1121"
104  "212"  "608"  "677"  "754" 
...
```

but it doesn't really work
So, How can I get the match ID then I can know which objects were in the same group.

I'd be really glad to receive any kinds of tips on this matter and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: `MatchIt` version 4.0.0 and above now includes the `subclass` column in the `match.data()` output for every matching method other than matching with replacement (for which you should use `get_matches()` instead). The answer below was only required for versions of `MatchIt` prior to 4.0.0 and is unnecessary now.

---

It is a bit frustrating that `matchit` does this. If you use optimal matching instead of nearest neighbor, in the `matchit` output, there will be a variable `subclass` that contains the matching strata. With nearest neighbor, you will have to manually create the subclass variable. Below is some code I've written to this. Note that it only works for matching without replacement, but it does support more than 1:1 matching, and not all treated units need to have the same number of controls.

```
#Getting strata from nearest neighbor matching
m.data$subclass <- vapply(rownames(m.data), function(x) {
    out <- which(rownames(m1$match.matrix) == x | apply(m1$match.matrix, 1, function(y) x %in% y))
    if (length(out) == 0) out <- NA_integer_
    out
}, integer(1L))
```

Now, `subclass` in `m.data` will contain matched stratum identifiers.

Comment: I edited your code slightly and now it works. `match.matrix<-m.out[["match.matrix"]]
#Getting strata from nearest neighbor matching
m.data$subclass <- vapply(rownames(m.data), function(x) {
  out <- which(rownames(match.matrix) == x | apply(match.matrix, 1, function(y) x %in% y))
  if (length(out) == 0) out <- NA_integer_
  out
}, integer(1L))

cbind(table(m.data$subclass ))` Thx a lot.